# Desk.com and RestSharp (oAuth)

Tags: c#, oauth, restsharp

This feels like it should be easy but...it's not.  It definitely doesn't help that there's no library for Desk.com, and the documentation is (in my opinion) extremely thin and lacking.

Anyway, I'm trying to use RestSharp to do something simple: grab recent cases. I'm using the Single Access Token method as we don't need to interact as any of our users.

Here's the code:

```
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource("key","secret","token","token secret");
        client.BaseUrl = "http://xxx.desk.com/api/v1/";

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.GET;
        request.Resource = "cases.json?count=10&status=new";
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        var result = client.Execute(request);
```

Result always just says the auth request was invalid and is unauthorized. Tried a bunch of different combinations, looked through the tests that are part of the RestSharp library, and read every meager word of the Desk.com documentation. Just not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 2):

You may have figured this out already, but you get that unauthorized message when you try to add the querystring to the RestRequest's Resource.

I was having the same problem. Daniel's "account/verify_credentials.json" worked for me too, so that's when I started to wonder if it had something to do with the querystring.

```
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.GET;
request.Resource = "cases.json";
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("count", 10);
request.AddParameter("status", "new");
```

Comment: Solved my problem. I tried to set the parameters in the resource. Had to put it in by parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say, that after following a lot of examples on making the Desk API work with C#, yours was actually the *only* one that did work.

I did not test with the resource you specified above, but used your code together with the "account/verify_credentials.json" resource. It returns an OK response for me, so your code works. So, first of all...thank you :)

Second (sorry if I am stating the obvious), I assume that you do not use the ("key", "secret", "token", "token secret") parameters as you specified them here, but use valid ones. You most probably do, but mayyybe there is a small chance that you may have found and copied that piece of code from somewhere else, and perhaps missed filling in your info.

EDIT: Since my first answer, I have put together a small (really small) SDK that can be used to connect to and work with the API in C#. You can grab the source code here: http://danielsaidi.github.com/desk-csharp-sdk/

Hope you get it to work.